# swift: Adding an action to an array of buttons

Tags: ios, uibutton, swift2, xcode7, addtarget

I'm designing a simple Sudoku app and need to trigger an action when any one of the 81 buttons are clicked.  I created an array of UIButtons in my ViewController:

```
class SudokuBoardController : UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var collectionOfButtons: Array<UIButton>?

  override func viewDidLoad() {

    collectionOfButtons.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    ...
  } 
}
```

I'm able to add the buttons to the Array from the storyboard ok, its just when I try to addTarget I get this message:

```
Value of type 'Array<UIButton>?' has no member addTarget
```

Is there a solution to this problem that does not involve me creating 81 different outputs for each button?

Thanks for your help!

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate through array of buttons and add target to each of the button. Try out following code

```
var index = 0
for button in collectionOfButtons! {
    button.tag = index // setting tag, to identify button tapped in action method
    button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    index++
}
```

Comment: Awesome, this worked, thanks Vishnu from a very grateful Swift newbie!  :)

Answer (score 5):

You have an `Array`, so you want to iterate over the `UIButton`s in the array. And because you're in Swift, you'll want to do so in a Swifty way, not using a simple `for` loop.

```
collectionOfButtons?.enumerate().forEach({ index, button in
    button.tag = index
    button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
})
```

This also nicely handles the fact that `collectionOfButtons` is an optional by doing nothing if it is `nil`, as opposed to crashing.

Comment: Thank you!  This answer worked too.  Much obliged.  :)